# Get data from same-domain URL using jQuery and append to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a website using Cloudflare. I'm able to view basic trace info --
 user IP, user agent, and, most importantly, the Cloudflare server used to route my website to the user -- on the following page: https://www.example.com/cdn-cgi/trace (working examples: https://blog.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace; https://cdnjs.com/cdn-cgi/trace)

How can I use JQuery to load the page and show only what's after `colo=` to the user?

For example, being in Switzerland, I see `colo=ZRH` (Zurich) on the `/cdn-cgi/trace` page and would like to show `ZRH`. So basically a partial `$( "#testdiv" ).load( "/cdn-cgi/trace");`. Usually I'd use something along the lines of `$( "#testdiv" ).load( "/cdn-cgi/trace #specificid");` but as you can see there are no ids to use

Thank you.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Update your question with the code instead

Comment: Done @TheophilusOmoregbee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: data is 'SJC',based on the https://blog.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace

```
let response=$.get('https://blog.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace');
let data=response.responseText.match(/colo=(\S+)\s+/)[1];
```